# Regarding Similarity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two $n\times n$ matrices such that $B=A^\dagger$.  Let $S$ be an invertible  linear transformation (say a change of basis)  of a $n$-dimensional complex vector space. Under what conditions on $S$ would it be true that  $SBS^{-1} = (SAS^{-1})^\dagger$ ? I figure that if $S$ were unitary then it would be definitely true. Suppose one transforms from an orthonormal basis to one which is not. Would it still be true that the adjoint of a transformation is  the transpose conjugate of the transformation in the new representation?

Thanks.

Comment: Your requirement can be rewritten as $(S^\dagger S) A = A (S^\dagger S)$. Note that $S^\dagger S$ is unitarily diagonalisable. Thus the right singular space of $S$ is structurally related to $A$.

Comment: The commutation of $S^\dagger S$ with $A$ implies they can be simultaneously diagonalized and hence must share the same set of states. Is this how you imply that the singular space of $S^\dagger S$ is structurally related to $A$?

Comment: @vnd $A$ need not be diagonolizable, and $S^{\dagger}S$ is invertable.